# how to block user interaction to image control in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

How to Block the user interaction for image control or object in windows phone7?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by blocking interaction for image control ? User can interact only if you give any event handlers like Click or Tap etc. If you don't give any, user cannot interact.

And if you already give and later want to restrict it, you can use either `isEnabled` or `isHitTestVisible` properties by setting one of them false.

```
myImage.isHitTestVisible = false; //Disables all the gestures like click etc on this control

or 

myImage.isEnabled = false; //Disables and greyouts the control
```